# Why does clang not always produce constant value for same static constexpr

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

```
static constexpr int
count_x(const char * str)
{
  int count{};
  for (;*str != 0; ++str) {
    count += *str == 'x';
  }
  return count;
}

#define STRx1 "123456789x"
#define STRx4 STRx1 STRx1 STRx1 STRx1
#define STRx8 STRx4 STRx4
#define STRx16 STRx8 STRx8

int test1() { return count_x(STRx4); }
int test2() { return count_x(STRx8); }
int test3() { return count_x(STRx16); }
int test4() { constexpr auto k = count_x(STRx16); return k; }
```

Given the code above, clang produces a constant value for test1, test2 and test4. Why doesn't it for test3?

```
test1():                              # @test1()
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
test2():                              # @test2()
        mov     eax, 8
        ret
test3():                              # @test3()
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     dl, 49
        mov     ecx, offset .L.str.2+1
.LBB2_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        xor     esi, esi
        cmp     dl, 120
        sete    sil
        add     eax, esi
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [rcx]
        add     rcx, 1
        test    dl, dl
        jne     .LBB2_1
        ret
test4():                              # @test4()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
.L.str.2:
        .asciz  "123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x123456789x"
```

gcc does:

```
test1():
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
test2():
        mov     eax, 8
        ret
test3():
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
test4():
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
```

Compilation command lines used:

```
clang++ -Ofast -std=c++2a -S -o - -c src/test.cpp | grep -Ev $'^\t+\\.'
gcc9 -Ofast -std=c++2a -S -o - -c src/test.cpp | grep -Ev $'^\t+\\.'
```

Compiler Explorer:
https://godbolt.org/z/V-3MEp

Comment: Because it doesn't have to. Compilers can choose to execute `constexpr` code at runtime if they so desire, unless you use that code in a way that requires compile-time execution.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay, but why not?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: What does it matter? It will vary from implementation to implementation; it can vary based on compiler options even within the *same implementation*. There is no way to make the answer genuinely useful, because it can change at any time. A compiler upgrade can change it.

Comment: It stops using the compile-time result as soon as the string passes 100 characters: https://godbolt.org/z/2mfA4j
This suggests to me it's a hardcoded decision by the compiler developers (to keep compilation times down?)

Comment: @NicolBolas Because curiosity.

Comment: clang has a couple of command-line options affecting constexpr evaluation, but I can't see anything that affects this. Hardcoded case-by-case heuristics sound plausible to me. [NB](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2019-July/062799.html)

Comment: I understand that unless it's tes4, then the compiler is free to do what it likes... and @Tharwen, I have realised the 100 character limit also, which is more along the lines of the answer I am after. But I'd really like to know, why this limit exists in the first place, or e.g. what the limit is trying to enforce.

Comment: I've posted to the clang mailing list and further tried to investigate with the following additional flags:

`clang++-devel -Ofast -S -o - src/test.cpp -emit-llvm -Rpass-analysis='.*' 2>&1 -mllvm -print-after-all | less -R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Tharwen's comment there is *by default *a of limit of 100 characters (or iterations).

This limit can be changed by using a really hidden option:

```
--scalar-evolution-max-iterations
```

> Maximum number of iterations SCEV will symbolically execute a constant derived loop (MaxBruteForceIterations: [Source](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ScalarEvolution_8cpp_source.html#l150))

Changing the command to:

```
clang++ -Ofast -std=c++2a -S -o - -c src/test.cpp -mllvm --scalar-evolution-max-iterations=1000
```

produces:

```
test1():                              # @test1()
        mov     eax, 4
        ret
test2():                              # @test2()
        mov     eax, 8
        ret
test3():                              # @test3()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
test4():                              # @test4()
        mov     eax, 16
        ret
```

View on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/drFCTo)

This limit and the option being marked really hidden, maybe there for a good reason. So I wouldn't go changing it and using it in production without suitable knowledge about it's effects (If I find some I'll update this answer).

For reference, [here](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ScalarEvolution_8cpp_source.html#l07522) in the LLVM source code (ScalarEvolution::computeLoadConstantCompareExitLimit), is where the limit is used for test3.

Answer (score -1):

Constexpr functions have to be called at compile time only in expression expecting compile time value.

You have to use:

```
int test4() {
    constexpr auto res = count_x(STRx16);
    return res;
}
```

to force evaluation at compile time.

Else you mostly rely on regular optimization of the compiler, which give expected optimization for `test1` and `test2` but not for `test3`.